# Creating a Binary Search Tree without an array

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So I have managed to make a BST in Java with using an array but a friend told me he has done it with out using an array. I know roughly how he has done it here is an example(I have left out constructors and getters and setters):

```
class TreeNode implements Comparable<TreeNode>
{
    private int value;
    private TreeNode leftChild;
    private TreeNode rightChild;
    private TreeNode parent;
```

As you can see you can just link the left and the right nodes but this got me thing to how the add method would work. So far I have just initialized a new object like this:

```
public void add(Comparable c)
{
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(c);
}
```

But this leaves wondering how can I link to the previous object if I can't access it like it was in an array? and every time I go to link a object I end up adding a new one. I'm kinda confused on how to implement this method, how would you do it?

Comment: But you're adding it to an existing node, right? So left, right, and parent have values.

Comment: Why array is needed in the first place?

Comment: When you are adding to a TreeNode - where are you adding - left child, right child or parent? In the 'Comparable c' parameter passed in the add() - the corresponding variable should point to 'c'.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/binary-search-tree-complete-implementation/

Comment: Well I first have to add the root node and then after that I can add to existing nodes.

Comment: So what specifically is the issue? Noting that there are tons of examples of this you could look at.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand how I set the nodes if i can access them - If i stored it in an array i could access them via indexing tree[0] for the root etc but with this method i'm not sure how I add new nodes to the right place

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you have to do is something akin to this:

```
class TreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private T value;
    private TreeNode<T> left;
    private TreeNode<T> right;
    private TreeNode<T> parent;

    public TreeNode(TreeNode parent, T value) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public TreeNode<T> add(T t) {
        if(t.compareTo(value) < 0) {
            if(left == null) {
                left = new TreeNode(this, t);
                return left;
            } else {
                return left.add(t);
            }
        } else {
            if(right == null) {
                right = new TreeNode(this, t);
                return right;
            } else {
                return right.add(t);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean find(T t) {
        if(t.equals(value)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if(t.compareTo(value) < 0) {
                if(left == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return left.find(t);
                }
            } else {
                if(right == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return right.find(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private TreeNode<T> topElement;

    public TreeNode<T> add(T t) {
        if(topElement == null) {
            topElement = new TreeNode(null, t);
            return topElement;
        } else {
            return topElement.add(t);
        }
    }

    public boolean find(T t) {
        if(topElement == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return topElement.find(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `t.compareTo(value) == 0` instead of `t.equals(value)` here.